# Proper way to pass values

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Assuming that we have the following class, is it better (in terms of oop) to pass the object of class `Foo` to `Bar` constructor rather than pass only the arguments `baz` and `qux` to `Bar` constructor?

```
class Foo
{
    public $baz, $qux;

    public function __construct($baz, $qux)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
        $this->qux = $qux;
    }

    public function main()
    {
        $bar = new Bar($this);
        //OR
        $bar = new Bar($this->baz, $this->qux);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sougata I would prefer `public function __construct(Foo $foo){$this->foo = $foo}` to access the properties of the `Foo` later.

Comment: If you need the all the properties then its all ok, if not then passing particular properties is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is reasonable if object of `Bar` class has dependency injection in its `__constructor`:

```
class Foo
{
    public $baz, $qux;

    public function __construct($baz, $qux)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
        $this->qux = $qux;
    }

    public function main()
    {
        $bar = new Bar($this);
        //OR
        //$bar = new Bar($this->baz, $this->qux);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    private $fooMembers = []; 

    public function __construct(Foo $foo_object)
    {
         // just for example
         $this->$fooMembers[] = $foo_object->baz;
         $this->$fooMembers[] = $foo_object->qux;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if there are any advantages when using the former pattern?

Comment: former pattern : could you point(indicate) to "former pattern"?

Comment: Pass only the arguments baz and qux to Bar constructor

Comment: if object of class `Foo` and object of class `Bar` will eventually have the same set of properties(`$baz` and `$qux`) then I don't see a benefit of such approach.  If two classes are independent - they must have different responsibility

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in terms of OOP the option to pass explicit dependencies is much better:

```
class Foo
{
    //...

    public function main()
    {
        $bar = new Bar($this->baz, $this->qux);
    }
}
```

In the other case you directly implement an GOD object anti-pattern. The `Bar` object doesn't need `Foo`, it needs `Baz` and `Qux`.

Imagine, that you need to create the `Bar` outside of `Foo`:

```
$baz = new Baz();
$qux = new Qux();
$foo = new Foo($baz, $qux);
$bar = new Bar($foo);
```

Do you see the problem? Now you always have to create Foo in order to create Bar.

Update: check this post - [Flaw: Digging into Collaborators](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-digging-into-collaborators/), it explains in more details why you should prefer passing dependencies directly.

Comment: yeah, faced exactly the situation you described. Well, switched to that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is better to pass arguments because they are explicit and code can be read easily.

But, there are some cases where the arguments are too numerous or too complex. Take this for example:

```
public function __construct(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
{
    if (arg1 == 1)
    {
        $this->property1 = arg2;
        $this->property2 = arg3;
    } else {
        $this->property1 = arg4;
        $this->property2 = arg5;
    }
}
```

In this case, only some of the arguments are used on each instantiation. It would be cleaner to define the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(Foo $foo)
{
    if ($foo->arg1 == 1)
    {
        $this->property1 = $foo->arg2;
        $this->property2 = $foo->arg3;
    } else {
        $this->property1 = $foo->arg4;
        $this->property2 = $foo->arg5;
    }
}
```

It does the same thing, but it would be easily readable at instantiation point. There may be cases where the argument scheme is even more complex.

I recommend reading about Builder design pattern. You will find examples of when to user objects as arguments.